# PHP | Only variables should be passed by reference | Why older version do not have this error?

Tags: php

There are many similar questions on web. And I understand you need to assign value to the variable before using end on  exploded variable.

Such As:

```
$var = explode(' ',$a);
$result = end($var);
```

But what if you do not want to save the first variable, it can be waste of resources if that variable is just for getting the final result. Why cant it be used like:

```
$result = end(explode(' ',$a));
```

How to turn it off on PHP, older PHP versions do not have these errors. Any way to turn it off?

Comment: An extra variable declaration isn't really a waste of resource. Garbage collector smartly trashes the memory occupied by it if there is no future reference to it

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just coding within the rules of the language, and you shouldn't be displaying errors in production code, however:

**PHP 7.0.0 - 8.0.9**

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference

- Disable `E_NOTICE`
- `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);` or in *php.ini*

**PHP 5.1.0 - 5.6.40**

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

- Disable `E_STRICT`
- `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` or in *php.ini*

**PHP 5.0.5**

> Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference

- No worky

**PHP 4.3.1 - 5.0.4**

- No error

Comment: @helvete  That's where I got it :-)